# Breadth first search for getting path

Tags: c, algorithm, breadth-first-search

So I have been creating a game in C where you start with a bunch of rooms, and you have to connect them with hallways, so what I have been doing is run a bfs on the screen and then get the through a whereFrom array. But so far it only works if the xStart and yStart are (0,0), if they are anything else something weird happens to the output, I will first show you my code.

```
u[0]=yStart;
u[1]=xStart;
eq(q,u);
int count = 0;

/*while there are elements in the q*/
while(dq(q,&u))
{

    uX = u[1];
    uY = u[0];
    /*if(uX ==3)
    mvprintw(++count,10,"%d %d",uY,uX);
    */


    /*break if at the end*/
    if((uX == xEnd) && (uY == yEnd))
    {
        break;
    }
    seen[uY][uX]=1;

    /*Neighbours around the current cell*/
    for(i=0;i<4;++i)
    {

        vX = uX + neighbours[i][1];
        vY = uY + neighbours[i][0];
        if(!bounds(vX,vY)||seen[vY][vX])
        {
            continue;
        }

        c=map[vY][vX];

        if((c == '+')||(c=='|')||(c=='-')||(c=='.'))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if((p->prev[vY][vX][0]==9999)&&(p->prev[vY][vX][1]==9999))
        {
            p->prev[vY][vX][1]=uX;
            p->prev[vY][vX][0]=uY;
        }
        u[0]=vY;
        u[1]=vX;

        /*enqueue*/
        eq(q,u);


    }
}

uX = xEnd;
uY = yEnd;
coord = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);


while((uX<COL)&&(uY<ROW)&&(p->prev[uY][uX][0]!=9999)&&(p->prev[uY][uX][1]!=9999))
{
    count++;
    coord[0]=uY;
    coord[1]=uX;

    uY = p->prev[uY][uX][0];
    uX = p->prev[uY][uX][1];
    if((uY!=coord[0])&&(coord[1]!=uX))
    {
        c = map[coord[0]][uX];
        if((c == '|')||(c=='-')||(c=='+')||(c=='.'))
        {
            p->screen[uY][coord[1]]=1;
        }
        else
        {
            p->screen[coord[0]][uX]=1;
        }
    }
    p->screen[coord[0]][coord[1]]=1
}
```

So even if I take out all walls and obstructions, it will only construct a path if it starts from (0,0), if the xStart and yStart are non zero, the path won't even show up. By the way dq and eq and dequeue and enqueue respectively, and they work perfectly, I already tested it.

Comment: How is `u` declared.  I ask because `while(dq(q,&u))` doesn't look right to me.

Comment: u is a dynamically allocated array. I am passing it by reference, and that wasn't the problem..

Comment: So if the start had only 1 neighbor, and that neighbor was (0,0), it would still fail?  And what does "the path won't even show up" mean?

Comment: it means when I record it in, p->screen, there is no path, so when I print it in main, there is no path that shows up.